# What kind of installer uses Microsoft to install Visual Studio 2010

Tags: installation

I notice that Microsoft uses they own propriety installer to install Visual Studio.
 What is MS use for installer? WPF installer or custom InstallShield?

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio uses Windows Installer for its package. It has a custom EXE bootstrapper with a custom UI, but the installation is performed through an MSI.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll take a look a custom EXE bootstrapper